# Como salvar dados de uma página HTML em um arquivo através de Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Não sei nada a respeito disso, e surgiu uma aplicação aqui no serviço onde preciso pegar os dados de uma página `HTML`, e gerar um **TXT**, ou um **PDF** , o salvamento será na própria máquina, pois o servidor é local.

Andei pesquisando um pouco e apenas encontro informações em PHP, onde tenho conhecimento nenhum a respeito.

alguém poderia me ajudar a intender como funciona éssa manipulação em `HTML/JS`?

Comment: Sem PHP? JavaScript puro ou com JQuery?

Comment: Não chega fazer um print para PDF? Podes explicar o que precisas fazer para percebermos o enquadramento.

Comment: com JQuery pode ser sim, como disse PHP eu não manjo nada mas se tivesse alguma coisa bem explicado eu poderia tentar

Comment: então Sergio, não posso fazer um print pois a tela está travada no teste em HTML, esse log teria que ser gerado em background assim que resetar tal teste

Comment: Creio que com JS/jQuery seja impossível gravar algo no servidor, porque os mesmos trabalham no lado cliente. Se isso fosse possível, seria uma grave falha de segurança. É necessário usar um script de servidor, como PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for em PDF, você pode usar o [JSPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) com o [HTML2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), um exemplo simples da sua utilização.

```
<div id="div">CONTEUDO</div> 
<button id="download">GERAR PDF</button>

let html = document.getElementById('div')
html2canvas(html, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                let retorno = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(retorno, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('arquivo.pdf');
            }
        })
```